# Sending header with CURL and recieving the Json data - PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I receive an error, not sure if this is an header error? The feed works 100% when I use Postman with the same headers and the URL

```
{"error":{"message":"The content version specified in the request is not supported.","code":101}}
```

Here is what I tried, my PHP code

```
$url    = 'http://x.x.x.x/api/slot/0/io/';
$headers = array(
        'Accept:vdn.v1',
        'Content-Type:application/json'

    );

 $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $headers

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);exit;
```

Comment: The error suggests there is a problem with your Accept header. Check if there is any mispell in the string `'Accept:vdn.v1'`.

Comment: @jorgonor I rechecked again on postman and my php code the Accept:vdn.v1 is correct

Comment: If it works in Postman, click the 'Code' link in the top right corner, in the "generate code snippet" pop-up select "PHP cURL". The generated code can be coy&pasted into your script and should generate identical http request.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for guiding me through the PHP curl code snippet, I used exact code, still same error (:

Comment: @AlexBlex that worked, thanks for your help, can you post this as an answer and I will accept :)

Comment: Glad it helped, but it hardly can qualify as an answer. If you compare your code to the snippet generated by Postman, you could spot the difference, post it as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the header from

```
$headers = array(
        'Accept:vdn.v1',
        'Content-Type:application/json'

    );
```

TO

```
$headers = array(
        'Accept:vdn.v1'

    );
```

that sorted all the problems